# Simple check to confirm access to a Domain Controller

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, testing, resilience

I'm preparing for a battery of resilience tests on a new network (which will be hosting a mission-critical application).

As part of it, I ought to confirm the resilience of the domain controllers. We have 2 DCs in this environment, and I need to be able to confirm that when I pull the plug on one, the remaining DC takes up the slack.

What is the simplest test I can do to confirm DC2 is successfully covering for DC1?

Would something as simple as `gpupdate /force` suffice? Or is there a better, *simple* test? We've got a lot to test so the less we need to do, the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually found a route that seems simple enough, though I've yet to try it out.

[See [http://adriank.org/how-to-find-out-which-domain-controller-my-pc-is-talking-to/]](http://adriank.org/how-to-find-out-which-domain-controller-my-pc-is-talking-to/)

```
nltest /dsgetdc:my_domain_name
```

Comment: Used in anger yesterday - did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following commands:

Query the domain for the current Primary Domain Controller

```
NETDOM QUERY /D:%USERDNSDOMAIN% PDC
```

Query the domain for the current list of FSMO owners

```
NETDOM QUERY /D:%USERDNSDOMAIN% FSMO
```

The commands will return the active PDC and DC(s) responsible for various FSMO roles.

Comment: thanks for the response, but I was really looking for something that would tell me what DC a given server was currently communicating with. With nltest, I could demonstrate that the server was talking to the PDC, but after pulling the plug on the PDC, and could demonstrate that the server was talking instead to a secondary DC.